# Elasticsearch 2.4.6 issue with delete and create index

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, lucene, centos

I am using elasticsearch 2.4.6 installed in centos 7 and was working fine. But suddenly the same has started behaving wierd.

I had initially created an index and now when i delete it does acknowledge, but if i delete again it still acknowledge when it should throw error of **no index found**

The testserver is working fine as below:-

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/taxsutra'

{"acknowledged":true}

[root@localhost ~]# curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/taxsutra'

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"taxsutra","index":"taxsutra"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"taxsutra","index":"taxsutra"},"status":404}
```

But when in production the result is as below which is incorrect: -

```
[root@server-03 ~]# curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/taxsutra'

{"acknowledged":true}

[root@server-03 ~]# curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/taxsutra'

{"acknowledged":true}
```

Similarly even while creating index in production server, the output shows the index exists even when it doesnot.

Appreciate Help.

Comment: it may take time in deleting the index

Comment: @Ijaz Ahmad Khan i wait for long enough time but still it doesnt delete, the question is when there is no index and i had just restarted the elasticsearch then how come the index exists on creation?

Comment: you need to curl the api or use _cat to see whether it still exist